How to insert a row in MySQL that dynamically uses other values in the table that match a SELECT query?
Suppose you have a table:
+-------+-------+
| Item  | Value |
+-------+-------+
| Tax   | 1.08  |
| Water | 6     |
| Bread | 2     |
+-------+-------+

And you want to insert a row like this:
+-------+-------+
| Item  | Value |
+-------+-------+
| Paper | 5*Tax |
+-------+-------+

Where the Value column is dynamically generated each time it's retrieved, so it always accurately reflects whatever changes are made to "Tax."
Example:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Item = "Paper" shows 5.40
UPDATE table SET Value = 1.11 WHERE Item = "Tax"
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Item = "Paper" shows 5.55

Is it possible to have dynamic values like this in the same table?  Or is this something I would need to use a view for?
Edit: essentially, I want this to function like a spreadsheet.  If it were Excel, Paper's value would be =B2*5

The logic for 5*tax belongs in your query or view.

You could join on the same table and have a query like this:
SELECT  t1.Item , t1.Value * t2.Value AS Value_with_tax
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.Item = 'Tax'
WHERE t1.Item <> 'Tax';

Demo: SQLFiddle
